# VBA Code Error - Unable to Replace Query Successfully (Error 1004)

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a button in workbook A that is assigned to a macro. This macro exports a query from workbook A to another workbook, B. The goal is to replace the previous query in workbook B with the updated data. However, I've ran into a conditional error. My code runs fine when the query in workbook A has the same or more rows than the query in workbook B, but when workbook B's query has more rows than workbook A's updated query, it gives me an error 1004 - Pivot Table cannot be replaced (Error is on a different line each time, but its either on the currentQueryTable line, set target querytable or set current querytable line). Any help would be appreciated to help fix this error. I've attached the code I use to run the button.

```
Sub ReplaceQueryTableWithRefreshedData()
    Dim currentWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim currentQueryTable As QueryTable
    Dim targetQueryTable As QueryTable

    ' Sets the path to the target workbook
    Dim targetWorkbookPath As String
    targetWorkbookPath = "C:\Users\notgoingtoshow.xlsm"

    ' Sets the name of the target worksheet
    Dim targetWorksheetName As String
    targetWorksheetName = "qry_ABB"

    ' Opens the current workbook
    Set currentWorkbook = ThisWorkbook

    ' Sets the current query table
    Set currentQueryTable = currentWorkbook.Worksheets("qry_ABB").ListObjects(1).QueryTable

    ' Opens the target workbook
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks.Open(targetWorkbookPath)

    ' Sets the target query table
    Set targetQueryTable = targetWorkbook.Worksheets(targetWorksheetName).ListObjects(1).QueryTable
    
    
    ' Clears the existing data and properties of the target query table

    targetQueryTable.Delete
    
    ' Copies the query table from the current workbook to the target workbook
    currentQueryTable.ResultRange.Copy Destination:=targetWorkbook.Worksheets(targetWorksheetName).Range("A1")
    
 
   
    ' Saves and close the target workbook
     targetWorkbook.Worksheets(targetWorksheetName).ListObjects(1).QueryTable.Refresh
     targetWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
End Sub
```

Comment: For what I can see (I'm not that proficient with PivotTables), you're only deleting the QueryTable of the Pivot Table, not the Pivot Table itself. Then you're trying to paste the Range [(documentation)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.resultrange) from "currentQueryTable" over the PivotTable which doesn't like that. Are you needing only the results from the currentQueryTable (aka only the Range) or do you want a new pivottable based on this range?